# Вывод списка с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, список

Всем привет.
Есть список

```
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Необходимо строкой вывести все данные, которые находятся в списке.
Хелп, плиз=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var out='';
for(var key in arr){
    out += arr[key].innerHTML;
}
alert(out);
```

**upd jQuery**

```
var out='';
$('li').each(function(){
out += $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: ОМГ, опять for...in

Comment: а в чем дело с `for...in`?
В ответ нужно добавить проверку `hasOwnProperty`, а в остальном все ништяк. Разве нет?

Comment: А для jQuery подобное есть?

Comment: @ikoolik for in не будет перебирать объекты имеющие флаг DontEnum. поэтому некоторые js разработчики панически его боятся и считают ущербным.

Comment: @FLK, ага, а тормоза придумали трусы :-) Это не инструмент для итерации массивов или, как в данном случае, коллекций.

Comment: 4 плюса за for in с массивом... Апокалипсис близиться...

Comment: @AlexWindHope `i = arr.length; while(i--){...}` :)

Answer (score 1):

Для JQuery:

```
   $('li').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/7mBmB/)